# AWS ELB DNS failover to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-elb, amazon-route53, failover

I am trying to stay sane here, but this config was checked several times now against several tutorials and it is just not working.
I am having a public facing ELB for my website with EC2 instance behind it. What I need is to setup a maintenance website, hosted from S3 bucket.
What I did is, I created dns entry A alias for healthcheck xxx-healthcheck.xxx.com pointing to ELB internal AWS domain name. 
I created an A alias for my website xxx.xxx.com pointing to my ELB internal address. Then I marked settings as failover, added above healthcheck and marked this as evaluate its health.
I added next record - for my S3 bucket (S3 bucket name is xxx.xxx.com). Alias A, again. Name of alias is same as primary address, so xxx.xxx.com. I marked it as failover and secondary.
I turned service off on both instances, healthcheck is marked as unhealthy. It is timeing out, when I try to access the website - no under maintenance site.

Please.
Please, help.

Cheers
A

Comment: Close your browser windows?

Comment: Your ELB is an internal ELB right? And S3 is public? You can open the website on the public internet?

Comment: ELB is public facing. S3 bucket is available for public. I can open a html file from bucket on my browser

Answer (score 1):

Are you using TLS/SSL? If your website from ELB is being served over HTTPS, the browser tries to use HTTPS even with S3 after the failover (this is normal and it's called HSTS). Your content will still be served if you use HTTP. To verity that, use a different browser or clear all history related to your domain (if that does't work, google "chrome delete hsts domain" if you're on Chrome), and open your domain using `http://<domain>`.

If you enabled static website hosting on S3 and added that static S3 URL (via A record Alias) as your failover secondary route in Route53, this will not work since S3 is not configured to receive traffic using HTTPS via your domain.

The solution for this is to create a CloudFront distribution and add your S3 bucket as the origin, add CNAME value in CloudFront as your domain name and attach/configure SSL certificates on CloudFront. Now, in your Route53, add the CloudFront distribution's URL as the failover entry (A record Alias).